# Erro org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: jsf, hibernate, ejb

Erro quando a classe movimentação está preenchida com os dados no banco, caso não haja nenhum registro, consigo acessar meu xhtml normalmente. Na classe conta eu corrigo com fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mas na classe movimentacao esse erro persiste, Vejam os relacionamentos:

Conta

```
@Entity
//@Cacheable
//@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "agencia","numero" })})
public class Conta implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String titular;
private String agencia;
private String numero;
private String banco;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(unique=true)
private Gerente gerente;

//@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="conta") 
private List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes;

getters e setters
```

Movimentacao

```
@Entity
public class Movimentacao implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String descricao;
private Calendar data;
private BigDecimal valor;

@ManyToOne
private Conta conta;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "categorias_da_movimentacao",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="movimentacao_id"))
private List<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayList<Categoria>();

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "tipo_movimentacao")
private TipoMovimentacao tipoMovimentacao;

getters e setters
```

Categoria

```
@Entity
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String nome;

getters e setters
```

Erro:

```
16:44:04,872 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/movimentacoes.xhtml]: 
javax.el.ELException: /movimentacoes.xhtml: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.caelum.financas.modelo.Movimentacao.categorias, no session or session was closed
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
```

...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.caelum.financas.modelo.Movimentacao.categorias, 
no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

...

```
16:44:04,924 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fj25-financas-web].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.caelum.financas.modelo.Movimentacao.categorias, no session or session was closed
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom consegui resolver mudando minha consulta no dao, onde a JPQL oferece uma forma explicita de carregar os relacionamentos através do join junto com a clausula fetch.

```
public List<Movimentacao> listaComCategorias() {
    return this.manager.createQuery("select distinct m from Movimentacao m left join fetch m.categorias",
            Movimentacao.class).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre porque sua lista de categorias está com Lazy, você precisa inicializar sua lista primeiro antes de realizar uma operação.

Você vai precisar criar um método de `init()` na sua classe `Movimentacao`.
Essa é a lógica que deve seguir:

```
 start Transaction 
      Hibernate.initialize(getCategorias());
 end Transaction
```

Segue uns exemplos no SOen:

[How to load lazy fetched items from Hibernate/JPA in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470065/5165064)

[Hibernate: best practice to pull all lazy collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19928568/5165064)

Comment: Através de uma consulta eu não resolveria isso não? Algumas pesquisas que fiz dizem para inserir o uso do JOIN FETCH e etc. 
Criando um método init esse código que você me passou ficaria dessa mesma forma? star e end dentro do metodo?

Comment: Sim, você tem que iniciar a transaction, iniciar sua lista e depois fecha-la.